# Difference between String Value and Binary Value in Registry

Tags: windows, registry

Can someone explain me when to use String Value or Binary Value in windows registry? Is there any security concerns also attached with these or not ?

Comment: In general use them as they are labelled, SZ for text, BINARY for binary, what is your actual concern?

Comment: I want to store date in encrypted format, should i still be using SZ or i can go for Binary.

Comment: Assuming the output of your process is a byte buffer, REG_BINARY seems appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to store date in encrypted format

You **must** use the binary format.  Encrypted data cannot be stored in a string.  It will randomly get corrupted when the string is normalized, not every byte value is a valid Unicode codepoint.  If you absolutely *want* a string then you have to encode the data, Convert.ToBase64String().